Optimization of render for a draggable component in React.js
I am working on creating a draggable component that should support gestures (dragging). I've encountered a performance optimization issue: the animation does not look smooth despite various attempts to improve performance. I notice that while dragging, the component stutters and doesn’t respond as smoothly as I would like.
I have already tried different optimization methods, including using requestAnimationFrame(), but it still did not help to achieve the desired smoothness.
For comparison, I noticed that the framer-motion library provides much smoother movement without such lag. I'm curious how they managed to achieve that level of smoothness. I suspect the issue may be related to improper render implementation, but I haven't been able to find an optimal solution.
I am attaching resources for better understanding of the problem:
It's worth noting that the component has been greatly simplified, and all unnecessary parts have been removed, leaving only the problematic section. Therefore, please ignore the code's cleanliness.

Link to the sandbox with the test: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/24rmvm

Video showing the behavior without framer-motion: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZUcLiyQywpL6oHUMP-5KwM6gQAei0xpk/view?usp=sharing

Video showing the behavior with framer-motion: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10aERUyDrba4AFp5qEqZhlMTd45D5Z_Js/view?usp=sharing


I would appreciate any advice or hints on how to optimize the rendering of draggable components!
I have already tried different optimization methods, including using requestAnimationFrame(), but it still did not help to achieve the desired smoothness.
